# Differentiation of bilinear form w.r.t. matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I need to do a derivative of bilinear form: b'C a w.r.t to Kx1 vector t
where "b" and "a" are Kx1 vectors and "C" is KxK matrix that depends on vector t (and a and b are independent of t). Does anyone know how do I do that?
If I try to apply chain rule and differentiate the expression w.r.t. matrix C times derivative of C w.r.t. t, then the dimensions do not agree since I get:
ba'*derivative of C wrt t
where ba' is KxK matrix, and derivative of C wrt t should be somthing with KxKxK dimensions, since it's the derivative of KxK matrix w.r.t. Kx1 vector....so I don't know how to multiply it further.

Thnx!

Comment: The formula is the obvious generalization of the derivative of a product. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541451/derivative-bilinear-map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with notation.

First note that the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{k \times k} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(C) = b^T Ca$ is linear and so $Df(C)(H) = f(H) = b^T H a$.

In your case, you have a function $C: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$, and you wish to compute the derivative of $\phi = f \circ C$.

Note that the derivative of $C$ at a point $x$ is a function $DC(x) : \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$.

The chain rule at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$ in the direction $h$ gives $D\phi(x)(h) = D f(C(x)) (D C(x) (h))$.

Using the above form for $DF(C)$ we have
$D\phi(x)(h) = f(DC(x)(h)) = b^T (DC(x)(h)) a$.

Since we can write $DC(x)(h) = \sum_{i=1}^k  h_i DC(x)(e_i)$ and noting that $DC(x)(e_i) = {\partial C(x) \over \partial x_i}$, we have
$D\phi(x)(h) = \sum_{i=1}^k  h_i {\partial C(x) \over \partial x_i}$.