# Chain Rule to Compute Second Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra

I was going through Marsden's book, *Elementary Classical Analysis*, and came across the following exercise in Chapter 6. It reads as follows:

> If $f: A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g: B \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^p$, show that
>   \begin{align*}
> D^2(g \circ f(x_0))(x, y)
> &= D^2(g(x_0)) (Df(x_0) \cdot x, Df(x_0) \cdot y) \\
> &+\; Dg(f(x_0)) \cdot D^2f(x_0)(x, y).
> \end{align*}

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689143/chain-rule-for-second-derivative/689328#689328) concerning the same exercise, but my problem was not answered here. I know that I am supposed to apply the chain rule twice to compute this result. What I do not understand is why there is an addition involved in the result to begin with. How is the use of the product rule justified here?

If I apply the chain rule once, I get
$$ D(g \circ f(x_0)) = Dg(f(x_0))) \circ Df(x_0),$$
where $Df : A \to L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ and $Dg : B \to L(\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^p)$. Clearly this is the composition of two linear transformations. But neither the product rule (introduced in the text to differentiate $gf$, where $f : A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g: A \to \mathbb{R}$) nor the chain rule applies here.

I know that we can view this equation in terms of matrix multiplication for suitably-chosen bases. But how can I differentiate the composition of linear transformations as written above? Can I view the composition of these linear operations as a bilinear form, and apply the generalized product rule to differentiate this bilinear form?

Comment: I give this as an exercise in my manifold theory course, too.  The lecture notes are up on my webpage if you'd like to see the set-up.  The key idea is to have two frameworks for the derivative.  (1) Think of the derivative as a map of tangent bundles and (2) As a matrix that depends on points in $A$.  Then express the 2nd derivative (tangent bundle formulation) in terms of the classical Hessian.  From there the result pops out of two applications of the chain rule. $D^2(g \circ f) = D(Dg \circ Df) = D^2g \circ D^2f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The composition of linear functions is bilinear:
$$R(S+T)=RS+RT,$$
$$(S+T)R=SR+TR,$$
$$\cdots$$
See [Derivative Bilinear map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541451/derivative-bilinear-map).

Comment: I see, this shows that the composition function $C: L(U, V) \times L(V, W) \to L(U, W)$ is linear. Therefore we can think of the composition of two linear functions as a bilinear form, and differentiate it using the generalized product rule to obtain the desired result.